# SQL Decimal data type set to (5,4) or (6,4) is rounding to two decimal places when creating table

Tags: sql, format, amazon-redshift, decimal

I have a question regarding the decimal data type in SQL. I have a csv file with percentages, unformatted to 4 decimal places (ie. 0.####) from 0.0000 to 1.0000. When creating a table, I define the data type as DECIMAL (5,4) which I expect to be 1 number before the decimal and 4 after (5 in total). However after creating and querying the table I am only getting numbers to two decimal places (0.##) I am using Amazon Redshift SQL in SQL Workbench/J if that has any impact. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

I have tried using the numeric, decimal, and float data types. I have also cast the data type as decimal or numeric when querying the table I created. I have also confirmed that the csv file does have the correct format (0.0000 to 1.0000)

Answer (score 1):

This is a “feature” of SQL Workbench/J.  It is formatting the returned data for presentation to you. See https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/options.html#options-data-formatting

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. It didn't occur to me that this would be an issue with the  display only